# Unable to save the resized images in the specific folder for cv2

Tags: python, filepath, glob, opencv

I am trying to write a code in python to resize the images in bulk from a specific folder and save the output to a different specified folder. I am unable to save the images in the mentioned outPath having folder name "Resized". Can anyone help me out in this...

```
import os
import cv2, glob

imgPath = "E:/Data/Ori"
outPath = "E:/Data/Resized"

images = glob.glob(imgPath + "/" + "*.jpg")

for image in images:
    img = cv2.imread(image,1) #1 for color scale
    
    res = cv2.resize(img, (400,300)) #width = 400, height = 300
    
    cv2.imwrite(outPath + '/' + image, res) #Unable to save the images in 'Resized' folder
```

Comment: Does the `Resized` folder already exist? If not, maybe writing to non-existent folders just doesn't work. Anyway, please provide some error messages, etc.

Comment: Yes, the "Resized" folder exists in E Drive. I am not getting any error messages. But images are unable to save in that folder. In fact, images are not saved anywhere also.